Prevent publishing of uncategorized posts
I'd like to prevent posts under the default category named "affitti" to be published. I tried this but with no effect
function prevent_default_category_publish($data, $postarr) {
if (in_category('affitti', $postarr['ID'])) {
    wp_die('Error: Posts cannot be published with the default category.');
}
return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'prevent_default_category_publish', 10, 2);


the code in your question would also prevent the creation of drafts and revisions, it's important to know are you asking for the block editor or a different editor? If it's the block editor then there are APIs that can be used to implement pre-publish checks that aren't available in the classic editor

@TomJNowell block editor

it seems it's not possible to accomplish what I wanted in PHP [link]https://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-the-publication-of-posts-with-the-default-category/#post-18092729

The in_category function works only on existing (saved) posts. Here you can directly access the category in $postarr like this:
if ('affitti' == $postarr['post_category'])) {
  wp_die('Error: Posts cannot be published with the default category.');
  }

By the way, are you sure you want to use wp_die for this and not some other error message? People may loose their work if WP stops completely when they try to publish.

No, I'm not sure. Any other solution? I tested the new conditional but it's not working :( I removed a parenthesis too, but it doesn help, sorry

Are you sure the filter is called at all?
